# How to copy the contents of the svn tag to the existing svn branch without recreating?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I need to copy the contents of the particular tag to the existing branch(ex:project1).

If i try to copy using below command:

svn co http://{url}:port/trunk http://{url}:port/branches/project1
It throws error as the branch project1 already exists.

I want copy only the contents of the trunk to the existing branch project1

Note: project1 folder is already exists(which is empty). I dont want to delete and create again, because the url is linked with jenkins
if I delete and recreate, the project will get disable in the jenkins.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Karthik

Comment: `svn co` is "checkout", not "copy". That would be `svn cp`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete + recreate.  I do not agree that should cause a problem with Jenkins.  Even if you already have the branch checked out, a simple svn up after doing this delete + recreate should still work fine and pull in the right set of changes.

Answer (score 0):

You created the branch incorrectly. If you want to create a branch based on a tag, you should `svn copy` that tag to create the branch. Since you did NOT do this, the branch now shares exactly zero history with the tag.

You CAN copy all the contents of the tag to the empty branch folder. You can do this one item at a time into a working copy, and then commit that working copy if you want it to all happen in one commit. But now the "project1" folder will not share any history with the tag. Each item WITHIN the folder will share history, but the top-lever folder will not. I would recommend deleting and re-creating even if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
  svn cp <SOURCE URL> <DESTINATION URL>
```

You should delete the branch project1 and then create the branch project1 by using the above command, this will not create any problem with your Jenkins that is because you are creating a branch with the same name which you have already specified in your Jenkins.